# Looking up values in a Vertical/Horizontal list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried every method i know, and i cant get it to work.
Don't know how to explain, so click on the snippet code to see what i mean.
I'm sure the is a way to do this, buy i haven't found it.

What i have tried is:

Hlookup
Vlookup
Index
And i have tried to use match on, but no luck.

i could do everything manually, but there is 25440 cells in my sheet and would take me all week.

so if anyone could help me with this! Thank you!

```html
<p>Sheet1</p>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">C</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">D</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">E</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">F</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">G</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">H</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">I</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Category</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Item Name</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 1</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 2</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 3</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 4</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 5</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 6</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 7</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center;">Material 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">Group A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p>Sheet2</p>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">C</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">D</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">E</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: center;">Item Name</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: center;">ItemID</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: center;">Material Name</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: center;">MaterialID</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: center;">Material QTY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">34</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 2</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">36</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">150</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 3</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">38</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">5</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">34</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">5</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 2</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">36</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">351</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">5</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 5</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">40</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">255</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">C</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">6</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 1</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">34</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">122</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">C</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">6</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Material 8</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">60</td>
      <td style="width: 20%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">134</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
<p>What i want is to look up the values in Sheet 2 so the Rows in Sheet 1 will look like this:</p>
<table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">C</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">D</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">E</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">F</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">G</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">H</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">I</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">J</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Category</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Item Name</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 1</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 2</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 3</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 4</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 5</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 6</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 7</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: center; height: 21px;">Material 8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">Group A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">100</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">150</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;">300</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; height: 21px; text-align: right;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">Group A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">B</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">200</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">351</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">255</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">Group A</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">C</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">122</td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;"></td>
      <td style="width: 10%; text-align: right;">134</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table will get you there.

Comment: Thank you!, why i did not think of this before !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used the pivot table to sett everything up as i wanted.